# Finding an anagram of one string in another

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this problem in the most efficient way possible.

Find if the given string contains an anagram of another smaller string

My approach is to create a hash table / dictionary of the smaller string (s2) and the number of occurrences of that string.
Iterate through the given string (s1) and see if all the characters in the hash table are found.

Right now the runtime of my code is O(3N) with O(N) extra space. I was wondering if there was a better way to solve this problem.

```
def contains_anagram(s1, s2):
    characters = {}
    for i in s2:
        if i in characters:
            characters[i] += 1
        else:
            characters[i] = 1
    for i in s1:
        if i in characters:
            characters[i] -= 1
        else:
            continue
    for i in characters:
        if characters[i] > 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about implementation details,

```
from collections import Counter

def contains_anagram(s1, s2):
    return len(list((Counter(s1) & Counter(s2)).elements())) == len(s2)
```